# Proving $\sum\limits_{\rm cyc} 1/(a^2 -b+4) \geq3/4$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, symmetric-polynomials, muirhead-inequality

Suppose $a,b,c\in\mathbb R^+$ with $a+b+c=3.$ Prove that $$\frac{1}{a^2- b+4}+\frac{1}{b^2-c+4}+\frac{1}{c^2- a+4}\geqslant\frac{3}{4}.$$

I tried various approaches, but nothing seems to work. Whenever I give a lower bound using $C-S$ or $AM-GM$ it becomes very weak. And I am seeking solution that uses not so much computation.

Comment: Have you tried using GM-HM? If you still can't make any progress, just wait for Michael Rozenberg to answer your question.

Comment: @Toby LOL, but quite true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a^2-b+4}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a+5b+3c)^2}{(a+5b+3c)^2(a^2-b+4)}\geq\frac{81(a+b+c)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+5b+3c)^2(a^2-b+4)}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that:
$$\frac{81(a+b+c)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+5b+3c)^2(a^2-b+4)}\geq\frac{3}{4},$$ which is true and nice!

After homogenization we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(17a^4+23a^3b+23a^3c-78a^2b^2+15a^2bc)\geq0$$ or
$$17\sum_{cyc}(a^4-a^3b-a^3c+a^2bc)+\sum_{cyc}(40a^3b+40a^3c-78a^2b^2-2a^2bc)\geq0,$$ which is true by Schur and Muirhead.

Comment: It looks a bit complicated, but nice. How could you find the factor (a+5b+3c)?

Comment: @Pseudo coder Just I played with $(ka+mb+nc)^2$ and it turned out. I did not think before that I'll get something symmetric, of course.

Comment: Much appreciate :)

Comment: I appreciate this solution, it's elegant in its own right. But I am still waiting for some easier method, that uses less computation.

Comment: @Aditya Ghosh Good luck to you  in your waiting!